# Defining private variables in prototype that are not shared among children and other prototyping tricks

Tags: javascript

I want private variables to be constructed for each child and not shared. (That's the minimum I need...)

```
function AbstractClass(){

var private_var; // not shared
// todo : how to create a static(shared) variable?

this.virtual_method = function(){};

this.some_fun = function(){
   console.log(private_var);
}
// todo : how to access static(shared) variable?

}
```

this base abstract class should be convenient enough for constructing many children out of it

```
function Child1(param){
    private_var = param;

    this.virtual_method = function(){alert('child1');}; //redefining

    this.some_fun();

}


var first_child = new Child1(5); //console : 5

var second_child = new Child1(16); //console : 16

first_child.some_fun() //console : 5;

second_child.some_fun() //console : 16;

fist_child.virtual_method();  // alert
```

Please help me... I need some working code to be a guide for me

Comment: You've said 'prototyping', but you're using neither Javascript's prototypes, nor prototype.js (I'm not sure which of these you intended). But because you're not, you're not using prototypes, you're not creating classes or objects, but just a (single instance of a) function, with its local data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the library **prototype.js**, look [here](http://prototypejs.org/learn/class-inheritance). (I'm guessing you do, because native javascript does not have classes).